# Issue in using WSDL2OBJC tool for my WebService

Tags: iphone, wsdl

I am using the wsdl2objc Tool to generate the soap Searvice APIs for my webservice. 
I am following this tutorial to generate code and use it

http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/wiki/UsageInstructions

&&

http://brismith66.blogspot.com/2010/05/iphone-development-accesing-soap.html

I can generate My WebService APIS successfully, but when i added i am getting 8 Errors and errors are

**Expected Identifier or '(' before '=' token**

Please tell me what can i Do with it. I am stuffed. the WEBSERVICE URL given in the tutorial work perfectly fine when i compile but mine code giving these errors.

Can anybody Help!

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use version 0.6, use version 0.7 instead. I encountered `cache` problem under version 0.6. The version 0.7 fixed this problem. So, my web service could use `session` mechanism to store state information.

Second, not any generated codes with wsdl2objc (or gSOAP) and WSDL will be compiled successfully. In practice, our team encountered some problems about compiling, so finally we implemented a proxy web service which provides an interface with simple class types (ex, int, string, byte) in order to avoid the compiling problems.